# Asp.net dll not found error for unused dll

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-assembly

My asp.net mvc project builds properly. When I try to run, i receive X.dll not found runtime error which is irrelevant to my project. It seems that, asp.net tries to load all dependencies of any dependency recursively.

I am sure that my code is not accessing any code in X.dll so what does asp.net runtime try to do? How can i fix it?

Comment: Possible fixes: Include X.dll into your deployment. Or don't use any code the (indirectly) relies on X.dll.

Comment: I dont have that dll. Because i do not need it

Answer (score 0):

The possible reasons for an asp.net project to try to load the dlls are

- Your references and dependencies of references
- You are not referring a dll but you can dynamically load the dlls using Reflection

  - In your code, You may be using [Assembly.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx) or any of it's variants .So at the runtime,this tries to load that assembly and it's dependent assemblies
  - Your configuration(web.config) may be referring that dll .For example you may have any configuration entry which will be using **type**

    `<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender"
      type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      </layout>
    </appender>`
  - similarly you may have an httphandler or module configuration where you are loading the type

    `<httpHandlers>

    <add verb="*" path="test" 
    type="MyHttpHandler.CustomHandler,CustomHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>`
- Another possibility is that you have this dll simply present in your bin directory.By default asp.net will try to load all the dlls present in the bin directory because of root web.config(**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config**) setting

  `<system.web>
      <compilation>
          <assemblies>
              <add assembly="*" />
          </assemblies>
      </compilation>
  </system.web>`

  - This one may be rare,I have seen CLR profilers [dynamically inject DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/profiling-overview)  to the process.

If none of the above steps help,you can find out where and why the dll is getting loaded using fusion log and process explorer/process monitor. Check [this](
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a method that has a local variable whose type is declared in X.dll. Even if the if path will take you away from the reference the jitter still tries to access it.

This bit me a few times before I figured out the rule. If any method gets jitted that could reference an assembly by any path (including a statically unreachable path the compiler can't prove; in C# you would receive unreachable code errors/warnings for all cases where the compiler can prove its unreachable), the assembly will be loaded. Furthermore, a try/catch/ignore in the method doesn't help. Only the calling method can catch the error. The exception happens on the opening brace of the method (or the : for a constructor that calls its base constructor).